# Initialize the bias term of the last layer

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I was reading the [this](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Focal-Loss-Explained/) blog about focal loss. In the section `Focal Loss Trick` it says:

> Facebook AI Research used is to initialize the bias term of the last
>   layer to some non-zero value such that the pt of positive samples is
>   small and the pt of negative samples is large. Concretely, they set
>   the bias term b=−log((1−π)/π). Here π is simply are variable instead
>   of the ordinary π. In their case, they set π=0.01, therefore b≫wx.

I want to do the same using tensorflow object detection api. Here, the focal loss is given by the following line in config file:

> loss {
>         classification_loss {
>           weighted_sigmoid_focal {
>             alpha: 0.25
>             gamma: 2.0
>           }
>         } }

But I don't know how to set the bias term of the last layer to some non-zero value. How to achieve it in tensorflow ?

Answer (score 0):

It's given by `class_prediction_bias_init` in the `box_predictor`. So, the config file will look something like this:

```
box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        class_prediction_bias_init: -1.99
      }
}
```